# Efficiently create a matrix from function values

Tags: r, function, matrix

What would experienced R developers consider the most efficient (yet still readable) way to construct a matrix with a given number of rows and columns from a given function, such that e.g. A_ij = someFun(i,j) with 1 <= i <= rows, 1 <= j <= cols?

Since I couldn't find something in the documentation I came up with

```
initMatrix <- function(rows, cols, fn) {
    A <- matrix(nrow=rows, ncol=cols)
    for (i in 1:rows)
        for (j in 1:cols)
            A[i,j] <- fn(i,j)
    return(A)
}
```

which seems silly and slow to me. Any improvements (particularly one-liners) welcome! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're looking for `outer(seq(rows),seq(cols),fn)`  (or as suggested below, `outer(seq_len(rows),seq_len(cols),fn)`: would need some examples to see how much difference that made).

You can gain a lot in readability (at least if you don't have to go look up `?outer` to find out what's going on) this way, but I don't actually think you save much time. Something cleverer and more efficient might be possible if your `fn` is vectorized to begin with: is it?

Comment: Or with `seq_len` rather than `seq`.

Comment: Thank you for your answering this one so quickly! As far as vectorization of $fn$ is concerned... unfortunately not. As you might guess I'm fairly new to R (I'm used to numpy/scipy, maple, and the like) which is why I haven't found out how to vectorize functions yet.

Answer (score 7):

have a look at `outer`:

```
> outer (LETTERS [1:3], letters [4:7], paste)
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4] 
[1,] "A d" "A e" "A f" "A g"
[2,] "B d" "B e" "B f" "B g"
[3,] "C d" "C e" "C f" "C g"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just write any function, you might get errors calling 'outer', so Vectorize it first.

```
fn <- function(i,j){ ... }

A <- outer(1:rows, 1:cols, Vectorize(fn))
```

Example where it won't work without Vectorizing:

```
fn <- function(i,j){
  return(prop.test(c(tables[i,1], tables[j,1]), c(sum(tables[i,]), sum(tables[j,])))$p.value)
  }
```

Comment: Could you provide an example for such a function?

Comment: Any function which doesn't work when called on a vector, the one I ran into this problem with was (added in edit)